# How to Filter Pivot Table and then Count Visible Lines

Tags: excel, vba

I am developing a userform that filters a pivot table and then counts how many visible lines there are after filtering to show available items.

I have gotten it to filter properly, but sometimes it keeps a previously filtered alias/chooses a random one to add on. I really can't figure out why it's doing this, and I've tried adding some things to prevent it.

The other problem is that when showing the total in the userform, it either shows 0 for the count, or the total number of values. From what I've seen online, I think I'm doing this step correct, and I'm not sure where to go from here. It needs to show the exact number of lines that are visible in the pivot table.

[Album of Screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wuUYf.jpg)

```
Private Sub txtLot1_Change()

Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim pf As PivotField
Dim pf2 As PivotField
Dim pi As PivotItem
Dim strPF As String
Dim strPF2 As String
Dim strPI As String
On Error Resume Next
Dim Available As Integer
Dim OrderMacro As Workbook
Dim SampleSum As Worksheet

Set OrderMacro = ActiveWorkbook
Set SampleSum = OrderMacro.Worksheets("PF Sampling Summary")

'strPromptPF = Alias
'strPromptPI = txtLot1

If Len(txtLot1) >= 2 Then

    Set pt = SampleSum.PivotTables(1)
    strPF = "Alias"
    strPI = txtLot1
    Set pf = pt.PivotFields(strPF)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    With pf
        .PivotItems(strPI).Visible = True
        .AutoSort xlAscending, .SourceName
        .AutoSort xlManual, .SourceName
        For Each pi In pf.PivotItems
            pi.Visible = False
        Next pi
        .PivotItems(strPI).Visible = True
        .AutoSort xlAscending, .SourceName
    End With

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    Set pf2 = pt.PivotFields("Box #")

    Available = pf2.VisibleItems.Count

    txtAvail1.Value = Available

    Debug.Print txtAvail1

End If


End Sub
```

End result I need to happen is the following:

1. User enters in characters to the userform.
2. When the userform sees that it's two characters or more, it filters the pivot table "Alias" field to equal the entry.
3. Userform shows the count of lines for the chosen Alias that do not have an entry in the "Finished?" field.

End results that are actually happening:

1. Entry works fine
2. The command to wait  until there are two characters works, it filters the alias, but sometimes shows more than one value in the filter.
3. Does not count correctly, gives either 0 or the total of all items.

Comment: Do you have errors disabled somewhere? I would think the issue is your `For Each pi In pf.PivotItems` loop - you can't have every pivot item filtered out... So you should be left with the last pivot item in your table + your `strPi` item.

Comment: Hey Dwirony, I don't have errors disabled anywhere, and I see what you're saying. I'm not sure why it's not erroring out either.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot instead - show all items in your pivot table, then hide the ones that *aren't* `strPi`:

```
With pf
    .ShowAllItems = True
    .AutoSort xlAscending, .SourceName
    .AutoSort xlManual, .SourceName
    For Each pi In pf.PivotItems
        If pi <> strPi Then pi.Visible = False
    Next pi
    .PivotItems(strPi).Visible = True
    .AutoSort xlAscending, .SourceName
End With
```

Comment: Hey Dwirony, thanks for the updated code! It works slightly better, but still shows more than one Alias in the pivot table. It seems to happen slightly less frequently, but it's still popping up.